# What is the difference between message-passing and method-invocation?

Tags: language-agnostic, message-passing, method-invocation

Is there a difference between message-passing and method-invocation, or can they be considered equivalent? This is probably specific to the language; many languages don't support message-passing (though all the ones I can think of support methods) and the ones that do can have entirely different implementations. Also, there are big differences in method-invocation depending on the language (C vs. Java vs Lisp vs your favorite language). I believe this is language-agnostic. What can you do with a passed-method that you can't do with an invoked-method, and vice-versa (in your favorite language)?

Comment: Do you mean "What can you do with a passed-*message* that you can't do ..."? If so, I'll make the correction for you.

Comment: The original concept in *object-oriented* programming was for *"messages"* to pass between objects. If you wanted to `Object2` to perform some action you would pass it a message saying *"do `SomeAction`"*. In programming languages, the syntax of that became `Object2.SomeAction(...)`; and it was then called *'invoking a method"*, rather than *"passing a message"*. One downside in nearly all languages is that `Object2.SomeAction(...)` is both synchronous, and is almost always limited to the same thread or process.

Answer (score 13):

Using Objective-C as an example of messages and Java for methods, the major difference is that when you pass messages, the Object decides how it wants to handle that message (usually results in an instance method in the Object being called).

In Java however, method invocation is a more static thing, because you must have a reference to an Object of the type you are calling the method on, and a method with the same name and type signature must exist in that type, or the compiler will complain. What is interesting is the actual call is dynamic, although this is not obvious to the programmer.

For example, consider a class such as

```
class MyClass {
    void doSomething() {}
}

class AnotherClass {
    void someMethod() {
        Object object = new Object();
        object.doSomething(); // compiler checks and complains that Object contains no such method.

        // However, through an explicit cast, you can calm the compiler down,
        // even though your program will crash at runtime
        ((MyClass) object).doSomething(); // syntactically valid, yet incorrect
    }
}
```

In Objective-C however, the compiler simply issues you a warning for passing a message to an Object that it thinks the Object may not understand, but ignoring it doesn't stop your program from executing.

While this is very powerful and flexible, it can result in hard-to-find bugs when used incorrectly because of stack corruption.

Adapted from the article [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1568732&seqNum=4).
Also see [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1571983) article for more information.

Answer (score 11):

as a first approximation, the answer is: none, as long as you "behave normally"

Even though many people think there is - technically, it is usually the same: a cached lookup of a piece of code to be executed for a particular named-operation (at least for the normal case). Calling the name of the operation a "message" or a "virtual-method" does not make a difference.

BUT: the Actor language is really different: in having active objects (every object has an implicit message-queue and a worker thread - at least conceptionally), parallel processing becones easier to handle (google also "communicating sequential processes" for more).

BUT: in Smalltalk, it is possible to wrap objects to make them actor-like, without actually changing the compiler, the syntax or even recompiling.

BUT: in Smalltalk, when you try to send a message which is not understoof by the receiver (i.e. "someObject foo:arg"), a message-object is created, containing the name and the arguments, and that message-object is passed as argument to the "doesNotUnderstand" message. Thus, an object can decide itself how to deal with unimplemented message-sends (aka calls of an unimplemented method). It can - of course - push them into a queue for a worker process to sequentialize them...

Of course, this is impossible with statically typed languages (unless you make very heavy use of reflection), but is actually a VERY useful feature. Proxy objects, code load on demand, remote procedure calls, learning and self-modifying code, adapting and self-optimizing programs, corba and dcom wrappers, worker queues are all built upon that scheme. It can be misused, and lead to runtime bugs - of course.
So it it is a two-sided sword. Sharp and powerful, but dangerous in the hand of beginners...

EDIT: I am writing about language implementations here (as in Java vs. Smalltalk - not inter-process mechanisms.

Answer (score 8):

IIRC, they've been formally proven to be equivalent. It doesn't take a whole lot of thinking to at least indicate that they should be. About all it takes is ignoring, for a moment, the direct equivalence of the called address with an actual spot in memory, and consider it simply as a number. From this viewpoint, the number is simply an abstract identifier that uniquely identifies a particular type of functionality you wish to invoke.

Even when you are invoking functions in the same machine, there's no real requirement that the called address directly specify the physical (or even virtual) address of the called function. For example, although almost nobody ever really uses them, Intel protected mode task gates allow a call to be made directly to the task gate itself. In this case, only the segment part of the address is treated as an actual address -- i.e., any call to a task gate segment ends up invoking the same address, regardless of the specified offset. If so desired, the processing code can examine the specified offset, and use it to decide upon an individual method to be invoked -- but the relationship between the specified offset and the address of the invoked function can be entirely arbitrary.

A member function call is simply a type of message passing that provides (or at least facilitates) an optimization under the common circumstance that the client and server of the service in question share a common address space. The 1:1 correspondence between the abstract service identifier and the address at which the provider of that service reside allows a trivial, exceptionally fast, mapping from one to the other.

At the same time, make no mistake about it: the fact that something *looks* like a member function call doesn't prevent it from actually executing on another machine or asynchronously, or (frequently) both. The typical mechanism to accomplish this is proxy function that translates the "virtual message" of a member function call into a "real message" that can (for example) be transmitted over a network as needed (e.g., Microsoft's DCOM, and CORBA both do this quite routinely).

Answer (score 7):

They really aren't the same thing in practice.  Message passing is a way to transfer data and instructions between two or more parallel processes.  Method invocation is a way to call a subroutine.  Erlang's concurrency is built on the former concept with its Concurrent Oriented Programing.

Message passing most likely involves a form of method invocation, but method invocation doesn't necessarily involve message passing.  If it did it would be message passing.  Message passing is one form of performing synchronization between to parallel processes.  Method invocation generally means synchronous activities.  The caller waits for the method to finish before it can continue.  Message passing is a form of a coroutine.  Method-invocation is a form of subroutine.

All subroutines are coroutines, but all coroutines are not subroutines.

Comment: "Message passing" can also refer to the way one calls methods in languages like Smalltalk, Objective-C, and Ruby.

Comment: Yes these languages like to think of it as message passing, but it's a subroutine that involves pushing something on the stack while suspending the method calling the subroutine.  The implementation is stack passed method invocation which implies the caller is blocked while it waits on the calling routine to return.  Message passing has no such semantics.  It doesn't have to wait for the routine its invoking to finish was my point.  That's the difference.

Comment: IMO the OP is not really discussing interprocess communications.

Comment: Neither was I.  I wasn't specifically talking about IPC.  I was using process in a generic way to mean any task running within an OS process.  But within a process you still have to pass information between parallel tasks.  It just so happens that both of these methods can also be used for IPC but it not strictly IPC.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference between message-passing and method-invocation, or can they be considered equivalent?

They're similar. Some differences:

Messages can be passed synchronously or asynchronously (e.g. the difference between SendMessage and PostMessage in Windows)

You might send a message without knowing exactly which remote object you're sending it to

The target object might be on a remote machine or O/S.

Comment: Apologies for digging up an answer for a long time ago, but with respect to "the target object might be on a remote machine or O/S"- is that truly unique to message passing or method invocation? If I've understood your implcation correctly, you're stating that as a property of message passing. If so, is remote method invocation in Java not a contradiction to this?