# What's the difference between methods and messages in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What are the "under the hood" differences? What are the practical differences?

Is there any difference from a users perspective?

I know you could use `def` to define a method, but could you define a message?

Comment: What do you mean by "define a message"? Is there any difference from a developer's perspective? No.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not sure what I mean by "define a message".

Comment: So, the practical differences are zero: it's conceptual in nature, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/3562272/438992

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @DaveNewton.

Comment: (Note that I'm specifically not addressing anything around interprocess communication, just what Ruby calls "methods", callable by `send`ing etc.

Comment: In Ruby methods and messages are the same thing, both technically and practically. When you define a method you could also say you've defined a message, although that terminology sounds strange to most Rubyists' ears.

Comment: Many years ago I learned it as methods are the concrete implementation of object behaviors, messages are the act of requesting such behaviors.  I can send a message `bibbitybobbityboo` to any Ruby object by saying `my_obj.bibbitybobbityboo`.  If `my_obj` has such a method, it will invoke it.  Otherwise, `my_obj` will respond by default with `NoMethodError: undefined method 'bibbitybobbityboo' for my_obj:My_Class`.

Answer (score 2):

When you send a message to an object, the object will (usually) respond by executing a method with the same name as that message.

You cannot define messages. You just send them.

Comment: You say "usually". What else might it do? Can you give an example?

Comment: How can you create an objection that responds to messages in such a way that doesn't call the associated function?

Comment: If there is no corresponding method, a `method_missing` message will be sent instead. If a method is aliased, the name of the method may not be the same as the message.